# how to change image on clicking it again?

Tags: javascript, html

i have developed a 5 star rating images using HTML5 & javascript. I have 2 seperate images(greenstar & redstar).

I displayed 5 seperate starimages in webpage. If i clicked a particular starimage(3rd redstar), all images till before that clicked starimage(1st,2nd,3rd images) should changed to greenstar.(4th & 5th are redstars).

if clicked a starimage(2nd:greenstar) from above example,all stars until that clicked one should turn green.(3rd ,4th,5th should be redstars).

The above thing is working fine. What i need is when i clicked 2nd star, it(1st+2nd are green, 3rd+4th+5th are red) changes from red to green & if i clicked 2nd star again, all 5 stars must changed to red.

```
function ChangeState (index, parent) { 
    var colStars = parent.getElementsByTagName ("img");
    for(var k=0;k <colStars.length;k++) { 
    colStars [k]. src = (k <index? "Images/greenstar.png": "Images/redstar.png"); } 
}
```

here "index" states which star number is clicked.

Comment: why do you want to do that? If you are trying to de-rate(undo the current rating) that is not a good way of doing it, there are a lot of scenarios that will disturb your implementation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just save the current pressed index, match with the new one, if the index is the same reset the colors.
Try it like this:

```
var previndex = -1;
function ChangeState (index, parent) {
    var colStars = parent.getElementsByTagName ("img");
    if(previndex==index){
        previndex = -1;
        index = -1;
    }else{
        previndex = index;
    }
    for(var k=0;k <colStars.length;k++) { 
        colStars [k]. src = (k <index? "Images/greenstar.png": "Images/redstar.png");
    } 
}
```